Monoidal category monoidally equivalent to skeletal monoidal category
The fact that any monoidal category is monoidally equivalent to a skeletal monoidal category is widely known(se e.g EGNO exercise 2.8.8) it seems that the argument most commonly used is: starting with monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ choose from each isomorphism class an element and define the monoidal product on this subcategory to be element of $x\tilde{\otimes}y$ isomorphism class in our skeletal subcategory. We have isomorphisms $\mu_{i,j}:x_i\otimes x_j\rightarrow x_i\tilde{\otimes} x_j$ which we use to define how $\tilde{\otimes }$ acts on morphisms.
My question is how do we construct the associator on this skeletal subcategory and how do we prove naturality?

You may find it helpful to break the exercise into two steps, which simplifies the problem and makes it clearer where you need to use which assumptions.

Show that (assuming the axiom of choice) every category is equivalent to a skeletal category.
Show that if you have a monoidal category $\mathcal V$ and a category $\mathcal C$ along with an equivalence $\mathcal V \simeq \mathcal C$, then you can transfer the monoidal structure along the equivalence to $\mathcal C$ such that the equivalence becomes a monoidal equivalence.

